# Not able to make successfully - undefined reference to symbol 'XCreateBitmapFromData'

Tags: make, error-handling

```
/usr/bin/ld: ../bin/libanttweakbar.a(TwMgr.cpp.o): undefined reference to symbol 'XCreateBitmapFromData'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [bin/surface_splatting] Error 1
make[1]: *** [surface_splatting/CMakeFiles/surface_splatting.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I tried to include -x11 in the flags, but I still face the same issue

Answer (score 0):

As shown by `man XCreateBitmapFromData`, this function is part of `libX11`. To use it you need to have the package `libX11-dev` installed (which you probably have), and add the library to the compilation flags:

```
gcc [...whatever...] -lX11
```

The "add library" syntax is `-l` followed (no spaces!) by the the library name stripped of the fixed `lib` stem.